# OneDrive api returning wrong last modified values

Tags: c#, rest, uwp, onedrive

I have a C# UWP app that uses [OneDrive REST APIs](https://dev.onedrive.com/README.htm).

The app queries for the application folder and retrieves all the files from this special folder (app folder).

```
string appFolderParameters = string.Concat(OneDriveApi, OneDriveAppsFolderPath, "/children", "?access_token=", App.Settings.Values["access_token"]); 
var appFolderMeetings = await client.GetStringAsync(appFolderParameters);
foreach (var file in files)
{
    string fileName = file["name"]?.ToString();
    string lastModifiedString = file["lastModifiedDateTime"]?.ToString();
}
```

While the query works fine, the value, especially the lastModifiedString is always **1 hour behind**.

My PC TimeZone is set to "Automatic" and the Microsoft Account TimeZone is set to CET (same as my PC's). Any idea why the API returns a wrong lastModifiedString?

Here are a couple of screenshots to show this issue.

**Last Updated Time in the browser:**
[image]

**Last Updated Time in the API result/Visual Studio:**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the lastModifiedDateTime simply is in UTC. In the winter, there is a one hour difference between CET and UTC.

To convert between local time and UTC, use the `DateTime` type, or even better, the `DateTimeOffset` type.

Comment: OK. Based on your comment, considering that the time is in UTC, I added the following code and now it seems to be working fine.

                string lastModifiedString = file["fileSystemInfo"]["lastModifiedDateTime"]?.ToString() + " +00:00";
                DateTimeOffset lastModified;
                if (!DateTimeOffset.TryParse(lastModifiedString, out lastModified))
                {
                    lastModified = default(DateTimeOffset);
                }